# Close Terminal using 'exit' when only one window is present, close window otherwise

Tags: terminal, bash

When I use the Terminal application I want to close it using the command `exit` if only one Terminal window is open. If more than one window is open, I want to close just the window that executed the exit command.

To achieve this behaviour I use the following function in my `.bash_profile`

```
function exit {
    if [ $(who | wc -l) -eq 2 ]; then
        osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'
    else
        osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to close first window'
    fi
}
```

Everything works great but the usage of `$(who | wc -l) -eq 2` seems to be a bit *hacky*. In particular this only works if the machine is used by a single user only. Are there any other ways to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice hack!

If you want to cover the edge case where there are multiple people logged in to the Mac and running Terminal then I suggest you change the if test to `if [ $(ps | wc -l) -eq 3 ];` which would mean your user had only one process running, the `bash` shell you want to exit and quit Terminal.

Personally, I use [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com) which has a preference (under "General") for "Quit when all windows are closed" so the app takes care of it. If you have got this far with `bash` I highly recommend iTerm2.

By the way, your method breaks in iTerm2 as it only shows one log in with `who` no matter the number of windows you have open. My solution can sometimes fail to recognise only one window if you close them quickly in iTerm2 as it takes a couple of seconds for the app to shut down the window server instance.

If you have both Terminal and iTerm running then it breaks everything I could think of as well but you'd only be doing that if you were a constant iTerm2 user answering a question at AskDifferent about Terminal. :)